# How to create a history of pressing ImageButton

Tags: android, imageview, imagebutton

I am a novice developer. Please help to create the code to display the history of pressing ImageButton (on Android). I have three ImageButton (IB1, IB2, IB3) and I have 5 empty ImageView (IV1, IV2, IV3, IV4, IV5).

When the user first time touching one of the three ImageButtons (for example IB2), the ImageView (IV1) displays button image from IB2.

When the user clicks a second time and touching one of three buttons again (for example IB1 this time) image of the first pressed button (image from IB2) is moved from IV1 to the IV2, and IV1 gets the image from button which clicked in second time – from IB1.  And so on an unlimited number of times, but history shows only the last 5 clicks. Here is the beginning of my code. Thanks in advance to all.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageView IV1, IV2, IV3, IV4, IV5;
    ImageButton IB1, IB2, IB3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        IB1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.IB_first);
        IB2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.IB_second);
        IB3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.IB_third);

        IV1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);
        IV2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView2);
        IV3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView3);
        IV4 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView4);
        IV5 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView5);

        IB1.setOnClickListener(this);
        IB2.setOnClickListener(this);
        IB3.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.IB1:
                IV1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                IV1.setImageResource(R.drawable.first_image);
                break;
            case R.id.IB2:
                IV1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                IV1.setImageResource(R.drawable.second_image);
                break;
            case R.id.IB3:
                IV1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                IV1.setImageResource(R.drawable.third_image);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your clicklistner you should pass the drawables to other imageViews
for example:

```
IV5.setImageDrawable(IV4.getDrawable());
IV4.setImageDrawable(IV3.getDrawable());
IV3.setImageDrawable(IV2.getDrawable());
IV2.setImageDrawable(IV1.getDrawable());  
// set your IV1 resource
```

Happy Coding ;)

Comment: Well @Valery you should upvote and mark as correct so it help others finding correct answer